# How to present a Python code snippet efficiently in LaTeX?

Tags: code, python

I am quite new to LaTeX and do not know how to present a simple Python code like this in LaTeX in a professional way. Having your solutions and examples will help me a lot to learn and progress.

```py
if transactions: Transaction.create_transactions() # if transactions = "true"
node.generate_emptyState() # empty state for all nodes
S.initial_events() # initiate initial events to start with

while not queue.isEmpty() and clock <= targetTime:
    next_e = queue.get_next_event()
    clock = next_e.time # move clock to the time of the event
    Event.execute_event(next_e)
    Queue.remove_event(next_e)

print results
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is the way I like to do. Of course you can change colors, font sizes, borders and so on.

You need [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) to use `minted`.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable,xparse,skins}

\definecolor{bg}{gray}{0.95}
\DeclareTCBListing{mintedbox}{O{}m!O{}}{%
  breakable=true,
  listing engine=minted,
  listing only,
  minted language=#2,
  minted style=default,
  minted options={%
    linenos,
    gobble=0,
    breaklines=true,
    breakafter=,,
    fontsize=\small,
    numbersep=8pt,
    #1},
  boxsep=0pt,
  left skip=0pt,
  right skip=0pt,
  left=25pt,
  right=0pt,
  top=3pt,
  bottom=3pt,
  arc=5pt,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  bottomrule=2pt,
  toprule=2pt,
  colback=bg,
  colframe=orange!70,
  enhanced,
  overlay={%
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}
    \fill[orange!20!white] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=20pt]frame.north west);
    \end{tcbclipinterior}},
  #3}
\begin{document}
\begin{mintedbox}{python}
if transactions: Transaction.create_transactions() # if transactions = "true"
node.generate_emptyState() # empty state for all nodes
S.initial_events() # initiate initial events to start with

while not queue.isEmpty() and clock <= targetTime:
      next_e = queue.get_next_event()
      clock = next_e.time # move clock to the time of the event
      Event.execute_event(next_e)
      Queue.remove_event(next_e)

print results
\end{mintedbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I use same packages before starting document and then same code, but it does not look like what you got. do i have to add any other code or install any library? using Overleaf by the way

Comment: @MWH, I don't use Overleaf, so I am not sure if they have all packages needed for that. Try to read the log file to see what it says.

Comment: How could the margins be reduced?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer `minted`, but you can also use `pythonhighlight`, which is a nice frontend for the `listings`-package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}

\begin{document}
\begin{python}
if transactions: Transaction.create_transactions() # if transactions = "true"
node.generate_emptyState() # empty state for all nodes
S.initial_events() # initiate initial events to start with

while not queue.isEmpty() and clock <= targetTime:
      next_e = queue.get_next_event()
      clock = next_e.time # move clock to the time of the event
      Event.execute_event(next_e)
      Queue.remove_event(next_e)

print results
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way to achieve nice results with `listings` without fiddling around too much is the [`solarzied`-package](https://github.com/jez/latex-solarized):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{solarized-light}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
if transactions: Transaction.create_transactions() # if transactions = "true"
node.generate_emptyState() # empty state for all nodes
S.initial_events() # initiate initial events to start with

while not queue.isEmpty() and clock <= targetTime:
      next_e = queue.get_next_event()
      clock = next_e.time # move clock to the time of the event
      Event.execute_event(next_e)
      Queue.remove_event(next_e)

print results
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. it also shows error. do you think it is not supported in overleaf?

Comment: What shows which errors?

Comment: @MWH I think overleaf uses TL 2016 and `pythonhighlight` appears to be from 2017, so you have to install it by hand. Just put the file [pythonhighlight.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pythonhighlight/pythonhighlight.sty) in your overleaf project directory. Same applies to the three `.sty` files in the solarized package: https://github.com/jez/latex-solarized

Comment: Is there a way I can add a label to the code so that I can use that piece of code as a reference?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{Piton}` of the extension `piton`. It uses the Lua libraray LPEG of LuaLaTeX (and require LuaLaTeX). No exterior program is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{piton}

\begin{document}

\begin{Piton}
from math import pi

def arctan(x,n=10):
   """Compute the mathematical value of arctan(x)

   n is the number of terms in the sum
   """
    if x < 0:
        return -arctan(-x) # recursive call
    elif x > 1: 
        return pi/2 - arctan(1/x) 
        #> (we have used that $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x>0$)
    else: 
        s = 0
        for k in range(n):
            s += (-1)**k/(2*k+1)*x**(2*k+1)
        return s 
\end{Piton}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

It's possible to use it in conjunction with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{piton}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewPitonEnvironment{Python}{}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}}
  {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Python}
from math import pi

def arctan(x,n=10):
   """Compute the mathematical value of arctan(x)

   n is the number of terms in the sum
   """
    if x < 0:
        return -arctan(-x) # recursive call
    elif x > 1: 
        return pi/2 - arctan(1/x) 
        #> (we have used that $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x>0$)
    else: 
        s = 0
        for k in range(n):
            s += (-1)**k/(2*k+1)*x**(2*k+1)
        return s 
\end{Python}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]